# How to add part in eagle board that doesn't have "pad" but only holes?

Tags: components, eaglecad

I would like to add this part https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/guides-de-lumieres-led/8796223/ on my eagle board.

I did the schematic (just to be sure it's in the project) and the "footprint" of the component.

My component has no pads only holes.

The problem is, I don't see it in my board design ...

Any idea to solve this ?

there is my symbol
[image]
there is my device : 
[image]
there is my component footprint : 
[image]
there is the library : 
[image]

Comment: display the appropriate layers.

Comment: So you created the footprint, the symbol, *and* the device? You need all 3...

Comment: @RonBeyer yes I forgot the device, I created it too !

Comment: What layers did you put the hole on? Please add a picture of the footprint if you can.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm displaying all the layer and there is still nothing :-/  I can see my component on my schematic.

Comment: the fact that it's in the schematic doesn't mean you've added it to the board.

Comment: I just added the pictures... what is weird is that I can't even see the holes (I think we can't choose the holes layer) :-/ And yet, when I removed all the layer filters I can't see my component on the board side...

Comment: What do you mean, "can't see the holes"? Do you mean you are using the PCB Manufacturer viewer, which is accessible from the BRD layout window? Holes should appear there. It looks like you can see the component in your design, based on your pictures. Right-click on it and make sure you know what layer it is on. Eagle uses tStop, bStop, Holes, and supposedly Dimension (but I didn't see it add/remove anything just now). I can confirm there are features on the first three layers I mentioned. Make sure they are active. Maybe try adding a fresh hole.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something that made it work ! I used the "replace" command to insert the same component and it did the trick. Somehow my library modifications weren't up to date even by using the updating button in the library manager. Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: Yes, once you place a device on your schematic it copies everything out of the library into the schematic file regarding that part. If you update the library, you have to manually update the parts in the schematic to match by using the "Replace". Updating in the library doesn't do anything because there is no connection from a library to a schematic/board.